# Insert value 0 in database by vb.net 2010

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, insert, ms-access-2010

I have an Access 2010 database, including table called `saleoper`. That table contains a column called `discount`, numeric type , default is `0`.

And I have a form containing a datagridview including a column `discount`, its properties numeric type, and default value is `0`.

I used this code to insert rows into the database:

```
For m As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
        operationscmd = New OleDbCommand("insert into saleoper (discount) values (" & DataGridView1(7, DataGridView1.Rows(m).Index).Value & ")", con)
        con.Open()
        operationscmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
Next
```

When I leave discount value null, or take value `0`, and use one row, it's accepting to insert data in database.

Also if I use multi rows and fill the column `discount` by values, then there is no problem.

Only when I leave one or more rows without value in this column, then it makes a problem with insert and crashes the program.

Comment: I've improved formatting and grammar (for better understanding)

Comment: What error do you get in the crash? Generally, stop using string concatenation for sql statements, use parameters to prevent -> sql injection.

Comment: thank you for your answer , the error was ( Error in input syntax )

Comment: At lease using string concatenation makes it trivial to check the exact SQL. So put a breakpoint on con.open() and then look at the SQL string you've produced. Should be clear then what the problem is.

Comment: thank you every body , i solved the program by codes , first i removed the default value of the column , then i made code below in the cell end edit of the data grid view

Comment: If Val(DataGridView1(7, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value) = Nothing Then
            DataGridView1(7, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value = 0
        ElseIf Val(DataGridView1(7, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value) > 0 Then
            DataGridView1(7, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value = Val(DataGridView1(7, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value)
        End If